# Set a selected date in textview

Tags: java, android

Problem is whenever i select a date from DatePiker it's show a current date in `TextView`

How to Set a selected date in `TextView` ?

Also how to set a Dynamic date if i open this activity then it's set automatically in textview.

Below Code is open a DatePiker Dialog :

```
case R.id.llDueDate:
                new DateTimePicker(this,null, startDateListner).showDateTimePicker();
                break;
```

**`DateTimePiker.java`**

```
public class DateTimePicker  {
    public Activity mActivity;
    private Date mDate;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private int year, month, day, hour, min;
    private DateTimeSelectedListner listner;

    public interface DateTimeSelectedListner {
        public void onDateTimeSelected(Date date);
    }

    public DateTimePicker(Activity activity, Date date, DateTimeSelectedListner listner) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.listner = listner;
        this.calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        if(mDate != null){
            this.mDate = mDate;
            calendar.setTime(mDate);
        } else {
            mDate = calendar.getTime();
        }
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }
    public void showDateTimePicker(){


        View v = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_datetime, null);
        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

        datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                DateTimePicker.this.year = year;
                DateTimePicker.this.month = month;
                DateTimePicker.this.day = day;
                updateDateTime();
            }
        });

        timePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
        timePicker.setCurrentMinute(min);
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hour, int min) {
                DateTimePicker.this.hour = hour;
                DateTimePicker.this.min = min;
                updateDateTime();
            }
        });

        new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listner.onDateTimeSelected(mDate);
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    }
    public void showDatePicker(){
        View v = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);
        DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);

        datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                DateTimePicker.this.year = year;
                DateTimePicker.this.month = month;
                DateTimePicker.this.day = day;
                updateDateTime();
            }
        });

        new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.title_select_date_of_birth)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        listner.onDateTimeSelected(mDate);
                    }
                })
                .create().show();
    }
    public void updateDateTime() {
        mDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, min).getTime();
    }
}
```

Below Code is a set a date in a **`TextView`**

```
public DateTimePicker.DateTimeSelectedListner startDateListner = new DateTimePicker.DateTimeSelectedListner() {
        @Override
        public void onDateTimeSelected(Date date) {
            txtDateTime.setText(Util.getInstance(AddTodoActivity.this).convertDateToddMMMyyyyhmma(date));
        }
    };
```

**`ConvertDateToddMMyyy`** function:

```
public String convertDateToddMMMyyyyhmma(Date mDate) {
        String outputPattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a";
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
        String str = outputFormat.format(mDate);
        return str;
    }
```

Always this dialog pike a Current date not a selected date so **Where i miss some code or Bug**

Comment: share **`convertDateToddMMMyyyyhmma`** function with question

Comment: see i'll update my Question @NileshRathod

Comment: I run your code and its working fine, its showing the date i selected from datepicker.

Comment: but in my case it's always show Current date 
if suppose i select 15/5/1994 but it's show today date @Jyot

Comment: please check my answer below i hope it can help you

Comment: ok i'll just check your answer :) @Jyot

Comment: If you are using instyant run, then disable it. It sometimes is causeng the app to run with old code

Comment: sorry i can't understand what you say @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: sorry, `Instant Run` - the feature introduced in one of recent versions of Android Studio, enabled by default. It enables the apps to be deployed to the device faster by installing only the *delta* (changes) instead of full re-install of the APK. Check the Android Studio changes, and disable it, as it is known to incorrectly deploy to the device. So you may run the app after making changes to the code, and due to Instant Run the cahnges might not be applied

Comment: i'll use android studio 3.0.1 not a 3.1.1 @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Ok, but how does it differ? Instant Run was introduced earlier

Comment: ok but what i change in my code can u explain me @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: no changes to your code. The code is correct as for me. Try to disable instant run, as I think that it is causing you this problem

Comment: ook let me check @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: i'll disable the **`Instant Run`** but still i have same problem @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Just create a class for datepicker and pass text view in its constructor.!

Comment: please can you explain me how ? @AtifAbbAsi

Comment: Sure @MohammadAli
https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Date-Picker-Example-/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/muhammadatif/datepicker/dateexample/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(Activity.this,                  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            textView.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" 
                  + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
        }
    }, year, month, day);
    dp.show();
```

Comment: and where i paste this code ? and also i have this code in my **`DateTimePiker.java`**

Answer (score 0):

Update your dateTimePicker class

```
public  class DateTimePicker {
    public Activity mActivity;
    private Date mDate;
    private Calendar calendar;
    private int year, month, day, hour, min;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listner;
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

    public interface DateTimeSelectedListner {
        public void onDateTimeSelected(Date date);
    }

    public DateTimePicker(Activity activity, Date date, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listner, Calendar calendar) {
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.listner = listner;
        this.calendar = calendar;
        if (mDate != null) {
            this.mDate = date;
            calendar.setTime(mDate);
        } else {
            mDate = calendar.getTime();
        }
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    public void showDateTimePicker() {
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(mActivity, listner, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Done", datePickerDialog);
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }

//        public void showDatePicker() {
//            View v = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);
//            DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
//
//            datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
//                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
//                    DateTimePicker.this.year = year;
//                    DateTimePicker.this.month = month;
//                    DateTimePicker.this.day = day;
//                    updateDateTime();
//                }
//            });
//
//            new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
//                    .setView(v)
//                    .setTitle("selected dob")
//                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                            listner.onDateTimeSelected(mDate);
//                        }
//                    })
//                    .create().show();
//        }

    public void updateDateTime() {
        mDate = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, min).getTime();
    }


}
```

create filed variables in your class

```
  public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener startDateListner;
    private Calendar calendar;
```

call this method in oncreate of your activity

```
 private void initializezDatePickerAndCalendar() {

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        startDateListner = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                setSelectedDate(calendar);
            }

        };

    }
```

Call this method when you click on button to show Datepicker

```
 private void showDatePicker() {
        new DateTimePicker(this, null, startDateListner, calendar).showDateTimePicker();

    }
```

Add this method also in your activity

```
  private void setSelectedDate(Calendar myCalendar) {

        String myFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        String selectedDAte = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedDAte, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // here you can set date on textview


    }
```

Comment: But for this code i'll create **`DateTimePiker.java`** class so it's a necessary to implement this code in my activity ?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can have a look if everything working fine

Comment: i'll paste a code in **`onCreate`** then this method is not resolve **`setSelectedDate(calendar);`**

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add that method, check now its edited.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but Sry this is not work for me this code have Lot's of errors :(